# VBA-Copy multiple charts at one time

Tags: excel, charts, vba

I have a total of 10 charts on a worksheet, 5 being in SI units and the other 5 being in ANSI. Each are divided into two separate columns. The 5 ANSI charts are aligned vertically in column "F". The 5 SI charts are aligned vertically in column "O".

I want to copy only the charts in column "F".

How would I go about copying them all at one time?

I currently have them copied one at a time

Code:

```
wb.Sheets(w).ChartObjects("Chart 9").Chart.ChartArea.Copy
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Plots")
    .Activate
    .Range( "F2").Select
    .Pictures.Paste
End With
wb.Sheets(w).ChartObjects("Chart 13").Chart.ChartArea.Copy
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Plots")
    .Activate
    .Range("F17").Select
    .Pictures.Paste
End With

wb.Sheets(w).ChartObjects("Chart 14").Chart.ChartArea.Copy
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Plots")
    .Activate
    .Range("F32").Select
    .Pictures.Paste
End With

wb.Sheets(w).ChartObjects("Chart 15").Chart.ChartArea.Copy
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Plots")
    .Activate
    .Range("F47").Select
    .Pictures.Paste
End With

wb.Sheets(w).ChartObjects("Chart 16").Chart.ChartArea.Copy
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Plots")
    .Activate
    .Range("F64").Select
    .Pictures.Paste
End With
```

Example of how they are arranged;
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a loop you could do:

```
Dim chartPasteRow as integer

chartPasteRow = 2
For each chartName in Array("Chart 9", "Chart 13", "Chart 14", "Chart 15", "Chart 16")
    wb.Sheets(w).ChartObjects(chartName).Chart.ChartArea.Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Plots").Range("F" & chartPasteRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    chartPasteRow = chartPasteRow + 15
Next chartName
```

If you want to paste all charts without having to specify you could do something like:

```
Dim chartPasteRow as integer

chartPasteRow = 2
For each cht In wb.Sheets(w).ChartObjects
    cht.Chart.ChartArea.Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Plots").Range("F" & chartPasteRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    chartPasteRow = chartPasteRow + 15
Next cht
```

This is making the assumption that each chart will get pasted every 15 rows.

Comment: I am getting an "Object doesn't support this property or method" error on the "ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Plots")..." line. Also please keep in mind that I want to paste them as pictures, without any references

Comment: Apologies. Pasting charts is confusing. Please try the updated code.

Comment: I am using the first code you provided, and its still throwing the object error

Comment: Well.... I updated it.. and I don't see my updates. That's annoying. I'll try again.

Comment: OK. Updated again and it looks like it stuck this time.